# How can I use colormap with lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to plot my code as a sequential plot using matplotlib with the summer colormap. In my current code, I've plotted it as a scatterplot, but I want to do this using a line plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import  LinearSegmentedColormap

cs2_35_1_10_11 = pd.read_excel('CS2_35_1_10_11.xlsx', sheet_name='Channel_1-008')

cs2_35_1_10_11 = cs2_35_1_10_11.drop(['Data_Point','Date_Time','Charge_Energy(Wh)','Charge_Energy(Wh)','dV/dt(V/s)','AC_Impedance(Ohm)','Is_FC_Data','ACI_Phase_Angle(Deg)','Unnamed: 17'],axis=1)

charge_cc = cs2_35_1_10_11[(cs2_35_1_10_11['Step_Index']==2)]

charge_cc['Cycle_Index'].unique()
for i, cycle in enumerate(charge_cc['Cycle_Index'].unique()):
    cycle = charge_cc['Cycle_Index']
    x = charge_cc[charge_cc['Cycle_Index']==cycle]['Step_Time(s)']
    y = charge_cc[charge_cc['Cycle_Index']==cycle]['Voltage(V)']
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=cycle, cmap='summer')
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage(v)')
plt.colorbar(label="Cycle Index")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Data, **similar** to that used to create this plot, can be found [here](https://web.calce.umd.edu/batteries/data/CS2_35.zip).

By changing `plt.scatter(x, y, c=cycle, cmap='summer')` to `plt.plot(x, y, c='summer')` I have this error:

```
'summer' is not a valid value for color " even when I add "summer = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('summer', ['#ccff33','#004b23'], N=50)
```

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **cs2_35_1_10_11**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include a mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: What's stopping you from using `plt.plot`?

Comment: Please add `cs2_35_1_10_11` to the question, as per the first comment

Comment: no unfortunately it didn't solve my problem

Comment: The data you posted does not match the code. However, `import seaborn as sns` and `g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=charge_cc, x='Step_Time(s)', y='Voltage(V)', hue='Cycle_Index', height=7, palette='summer')` will probably do what you want.

Comment: To use the code as is you can use `cmap = mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('summer').resampled(len(charge_cc['Cycle_Index'].unique()))` and `colors = cmap(np.arange(0, cmap.N))` which will be your list of colors to iterate through and pass to `c=`.

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/occqF.png) using the sample data provided. Resolved as per the information in the duplicates.

Comment: thank you so much, your seaborn code worked ,it just needs some edits in for loop

Comment: You're welcome. The seaborn code shouldn't need a loop.

Comment: thanks a lot ,my problem has solved completely